# How to apply dropout to the outputs of an RNN in TensorFlow Eager using the Keras API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, dropout

I would like to apply dropout to the outputs from an RNN. For example, in Tensorflow 1.8.0, I could do this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

tfe.enable_eager_execution()

x = tf.random_uniform((10, 5, 3))

gru_cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(2)
gru_cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(gru_cell1, output_keep_prob=0.5)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([gru_cell1])
init_state = cell.zero_state(10, tf.float32)

cell_output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x,
                                   initial_state=init_state, time_major=False)
cell_output
```

How can I achieve the same thing using the Keras API?

I have thought of the following two ways but they were unsuccessful:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

tfe.enable_eager_execution()

# Attempt 1
x = tf.random_uniform((10, 5, 3))

gru_layer = tf.keras.layers.GRU(2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(10, 5, 3))
gru_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(gru_layer)

# Gives the following error:
# ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object
#  at 0x000001C520681F60>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.layers.recurrent.GRU'>) 
# to a Tensor.

# Attempt 2
x = tf.random_uniform((10, 5, 3))

gru_layer = tf.keras.layers.GRU(2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(10, 5, 3))
gru_layer = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))(gru_layer)

# Gives the following error:
# ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.
```

Comment: You're probably missing the input shape parameters to keras layers

Comment: @BallpointBent thanks for your input. I've tried it but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Why not just use `keras.layers` with the tensorflow backend?

Comment: @BallpointBen  Because I find it easier to debug my model when working in Eager mode.

Comment: From the code your post here, don't see how `x` is connected with the rest. According to Keras [Model (functional API)](https://keras.io/models/model/), neural nets usually start with the `Input` layers. You chain the layers up.  Then you create the `Model` from the inputs and outputs.  Then you compile the model.  Then you call `fit()` on the model. That's when you pass in `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the model output, without training, like you're doing in the TF code, the following code should work. Indeed, you need an `Input` layer, and to hook each layer to the previous one, and a `Model` as well:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dropout, GRU, Input

x = np.random.randn(10, 5, 3)

inputs = Input(shape=(5, 3))
gru_layer = GRU(2, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
gru_layer = Dropout(0.5)(gru_layer)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=gru_layer)

output = model.predict(x)
```

Comment: There is a slight problem with this, this applies dropout across all timesteps meaning that some timesteps can be completely dropped. To dropout every timestep independently, you need to specify `noise_shape=(batch_size, 1, features)` [doc](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dropout).